# What happened to seeing newest users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I like being able to see who has recently joined gis.se.  I think it is a good way to monitor growth.  When I looked this morning I don't see the "newest" tab.  Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: Looks like it was removed during the redesign, also see this question on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81136/bring-back-the-newest-tab-on-the-users-page

Comment: @scw  thanks, I also see discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/redesigning-the-users-page

Comment: Looks like its back: http://gis.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers&filter=all

Comment: this is not sorted by join date though, hopefully they're working on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're in the process of redesigning the user page

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-users-page/

I'll look at adding a "by date" subsort to the new users tab.

Comment: Great! it is a relief knowing I will never appear under an "oldest" user tab.

Comment: @kirk this is now complete http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers